# Rhomobile rhodes Rho AsyncHttp post

Tags: rhomobile

I am having problems with Rhomobile rhodes, plaese can someone tell me how to make http post, get, put, and delete using Rho::AsyncHttp?
I've been trying it to no success for hours.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some sample code to place in your controller.rb file

Here's the initial call

```
  def index
  Rho::AsyncHttp.get(
    :url => 'http://the.page.you.want.to.get',
    :callback => (url_for :action => :httpget_callback),
    :callback_param => "" )      
  render :action => :wait
```

end

the code above will initiate the httpget_callback method (below)
while that goes off and loads the url it'll change the screen and load the wait.erb file

```
  def httpget_callback
if @params['status'] != 'ok'
    @@error_params = @params
    WebView.navigate(url_for :action => :show_error )        
else
    @html = @params['body']
end
    WebView.navigate ( url_for :action => :show_result )
```

end

Without getting too far into it - the body of the returned page is placed into @html variable
Hope that helps, if you need more help, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have a sample of  get an post
res = Rho::AsyncHttp.post(:url => 'http://192.168.1.64/WebServiceTest/Service.asmx/Sumar')
 @msg= "Sync http call: #{res}"

http://wiki.rhomobile.com/index.php/RhodesConnectToWebServices

Answer (score 0):

I'm often struggling with the nuances of AsyncHttp in Rhodes as well, so I can't claim mastery yet, but I really felt the need to chime in with a suggestion:

I find using the Firebug plugin of Firefox to be VERY helpful when debugging my Rhodes app. You can hook it up very easily! You can load your app with any browser by configuring the web server to run on a specific port. This setting is in `rhoconfig.txt` and it is called `local_server_port`.

This is specifically helpful because you can easily survey the HTML and raw data of requests/responses and use the console to run javascript commands and play with the DOM and web page in realtime.